# converting Actionscript 2 code into Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, papervision3d

Recently I followed and made the 3d carousel in AS2, but I'm looking to use it and make it in AS3. Is there any possible way of converting the code so the carousel can work in AS3?

Below is the code for the AS2 carousel:

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;

var numOfItems:Number;
var radiusX:Number = 300;
var radiusY:Number = 75;
var centerX:Number = Stage.width / 2;
var centerY:Number = Stage.height / 2;
var speed:Number = 0.05;
var perspective:Number = 130;
var home:MovieClip = this;

var tooltip:MovieClip = this.attachMovie("tooltip","tooltip",10000);
tooltip._alpha = 0;

var xml:XML = new XML();
xml.ignoreWhite = true;

xml.onLoad = function()
{
   var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
   numOfItems = nodes.length;
   for(var i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
   {
      var t = home.attachMovie("item","item"+i,i+1);
      t.angle = i * ((Math.PI*2)/numOfItems);
      t.onEnterFrame = mover;
      t.toolText = nodes[i].attributes.tooltip;
      t.icon.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
      t.r.inner.loadMovie(nodes[i].attributes.image);
      t.icon.onRollOver = over;
      t.icon.onRollOut = out;
      t.icon.onRelease = released;
   }
}

function over()
{
   home.tooltip.tipText.text = this._parent.toolText;
   home.tooltip._x = this._parent._x;
   home.tooltip._y = this._parent._y - this._parent._height/2;
   home.tooltip.onEnterFrame = Delegate.create(this,moveTip);
   home.tooltip._alpha = 100;
}

function out()
{
   delete home.tooltip.onEnterFrame;
   home.tooltip._alpha = 0;
}

function released()
{
   trace(this._parent.toolText);
}

function moveTip()
{
   home.tooltip._x = this._parent._x;
   home.tooltip._y = this._parent._y - this._parent._height/2;
}

xml.load("icons.xml");

function mover()
{
   this._x = Math.cos(this.angle) * radiusX + centerX;
   this._y = Math.sin(this.angle) * radiusY + centerY;
   var s = (this._y - perspective) /(centerY+radiusY-perspective);
   this._xscale = this._yscale = s*100;
   this.angle += this._parent.speed;
   this.swapDepths(Math.round(this._xscale) + 100);
}

this.onMouseMove = function()
{
   speed = (this._xmouse-centerX)/2500;
}
```

When I add this code in AS3 I get the following error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1172: Definition mx.utils:Delegate could not be found.
>   Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1172: Definition mx.utils:Delegate could not be found.
>   Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 41 1120: Access of undefined property Delegate.
>   Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 6 1119: Access of possibly undefined property width through a reference with static type Class.
>   Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7 1119: Access of possibly undefined property height through a reference with static type Class.

I'm quite new to AS2 and AS3 but after some research I understand that `import mx.utils.Delegate;` is no longer need in AS3 as it already has delegate and they are already built in so in the code so I delete the delegate which are line 1 and line 41 and got two errors:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 6 1119: Access of possibly undefined property width through a reference with static type Class.
>   Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 7 1119: Access of possibly undefined property height through a reference with static type Class.

Now I cant figure out what to do so can someone help me convert this code from AS2 to AS3?

Comment: Can you upload your fla and xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few things to address here:

Your mouse events need to be changed to as3 calls
**t.icon.onRollOver = over**, in as3 looks more like **t.icon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, over);**

**attachMovie** is no longer used in as3.
you need to **export for actionscript** the movie you want to get from the library with a unique class name, then use **new someName();** to create it.  Then it must be added to the display list with **addChild**

**onEnterFrame** is not used in as3, you need to create an enterframe event more like this:  **addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, someFunction);

**delegate** is not used in as3.

flags on _x, _y, _parent, _alpha etc have been removed in as3.  just use x,y, parent, alpha etc.

**swapDepths** has been removed from as3,  You need to use the **display list** to add/remove/swap levels.

sounds like you might need to study up a little on as3 before you can properly tackle this one!  try checking out this link for comparisons between as2 and as3 functionality.

http://www.actionscriptcheatsheet.com/downloads/as3cs_migration.pdf

Comment: thanks for the info but im really new to AS ive tried convert it, replacing each action but i can find it, in the migration list the actions that have been removed in AS3 dont have a replacement so i dont know what to do

Comment: I have an as3 carousel somewhere.  I need to dig it up and I'll post it.  Will try and find it today.